Access 2019: Dealing with NULL values through OLEDB
I have a Microsoft Access 2019 database and have some data that I need to display on an internal website page. About few years ago, I created a main query that pulls together data from a number of tables. In order to get at the data I needed, I had to create some sub-queries that summarize some data to "feed" the main query.
To display the data on the web page I am using OLEDB and executing the main query. The connection string I am using is "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=D:\xxxxx.accdb;" The query I execute is "select * from Budgets".
For years this worked fine but then I started getting "invalid use of NULL" errors. When investigating, I found some columns in the access database that indeed contained NULLS that shouldn't have. I fixed those and everything was good again. A few months back I started getting those errors again. I checked the columns that were the problem before but all is good. Access does not give any clues as to what is causing the error. I suspect something in the sub-queries but without any clues I have not found anything. I have revisited this problem again and again looking at different things and searching the web for new things to look at and try but have found nothing so far.
Note that the main query and sub-queries all run without errors when run from within Microsoft Access. The "invalid use of NULL" errors only happen when accessing from outside of Access.
I have tried anything and everything I could think of.  I searched the web and searched the Stack Overflow posts regarding OLEDB but found no suggestions that have solved the problem.
Any help would be immensely appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Chuck R.

Somehow the backend allowed the insert of NULL value, which normally isn't an issue, unless your front end doesn't know how to deal with null.  Such as, if you pull a recordset and it has null values, it won't find ANYTHING, but if it has EMPTY values it will find the values as empty, thus returning a record.  Therefore, you need to validate EACH variable against the value of null, ISNULL(var) = TRUE/FALSE, and convert the type to EMPTY "" or something else, if its an Integer it will require a 0 and things like this.

TLDR version - Find out which data types are NULL, convert them to the proper "NON" value either "" Empty, or 0 if its Integer, like mentioned above.  And then your querry should work again.  That being said, back everything up before changing anything.

Ohhh wait .. you said the error happens OUTSIDE of access .. okay .. something that is being parsed and passed to it isn't parsing it correctly and all we have is a story about the problem and no data to consider.  Or in other words we need some code to look at for the outside access.  What front end are you using ?

Thanks @easleyfixed.  I have all the same thoughts and investigated them but came up empty.  The thing that is making this so difficult is that the error message doesn't give any clues to what is actually causing the problem.  The thing is that is all works when the main query is executed within Access it only fails when calling the same query from outside Access via OleDB.  I will have to do another "deep dive" into the various queries and data types of all of the Access columns involved.
